# JSON-RPC exception

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7.1, json-rpc

I use json-rpc client from json-rpc.net in my windows phone application. 
Code:

```
 var client = new AustinHarris.JsonRpc.JsonRpcClient(new Uri("http://www.raboof.com/projects/jayrock/demo.ashx"));
var myObs = client.Invoke<string>("echo", "hello world", Scheduler.ThreadPool);
myObs.Subscribe(
    onNext: _ =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_.Result);
    });
        }
```

And then I want get data, application exit with JsonReaderException :

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException
  Message=Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Line 0, position 0.
  LineNumber=0
  LinePosition=0
  Path=""
  StackTrace:
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadInternal()
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter, Boolean inArray)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value)
       at AustinHarris.JsonRpc.JsonRpcClient.<>c__DisplayClassa`1.<>c__DisplayClassc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<Invoke>b__9(IAsyncResult riar)
       at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.<InvokeGetResponseCallback>b__8(Object state2)
       at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)
       at System.Threading.Timer.ring()
```

Comment: If it's getting '<' back as the first character, are you sure it's a JSON-RPC service? Looks like REST+XML, XML-RPC, or SOAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the json-rpc client parser code breaks when receiving a response, and it dies on the first character (`Line 0, position 0`) which happens to be a `<` character, you'd have to suspect the service has returned XML.

Are you sure you're speaking to the right service endpoint? With the right protocol?